# JavaFTD2xx OS not supported error for 8 Channel Relay

Tags: java

I just got an 8 Channel Sain Smart USB relay here: [http://www.amazon.com/SainSmart-Eight-Channel-Relay-Automation/dp/B0093Y89DE/ref=sr_1_sc_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1443224362&sr=8-1-spell&keywords=8+channel+relay+sain+smart](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0093Y89DE)

I am trying to connect to the device on my windows 64 bit computer with java. I have downloaded all of the source code for the JAVAFTD2xx project which is supposed to utilize the ftd2xx driver located on github.

The ftd2xx driver that I downloaded is located here http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/D2XX.htm

I downloaded the 64 bit windows version and ran the executable.

I then opened the JAVAFTD2xx project in netbeans and created a main class. Here is the code for my main class.

```
 List<FTDevice> fTDevices;
     //fTDevices= FTDevice.getDevices(true);
     fTDevices = FTDevice.getDevices();
     for (FTDevice fTDevice : fTDevices) {

        System.out.println("fTDevice:" + fTDevice);
        System.out.println("fTDevice.DevType:" + fTDevice.getDevType());
        System.out.println("fTDevice.DevID:" + fTDevice.getDevID());
        System.out.println("fTDevice.DevLocationID:" + fTDevice.getDevLocationID());

        fTDevice.open();
        fTDevice.setBaudRate(9600);
        fTDevice.setDataCharacteristics(WordLength.BITS_8, StopBits.STOP_BITS_1, Parity.PARITY_NONE);
        fTDevice.setTimeouts(1000, 1000);

        fTDevice.setBitMode((byte)0xFF, BitModes.BITMODE_SYNC_BITBANG);

        // Set true (energised) or false (not energised) for each relay (1 to 4)
        boolean relayStates[] = { true, true, true, true };

        int value = 0;
        for (int i=0; i < relayStates.length; i++) {
           if (relayStates[i]) value += (1 << i);
        }
        fTDevice.write(value);

        fTDevice.close();
     }
```

The error I am getting is that the operating system is not supported. As I look further into the code, the issue is that the input stream is null for the code below.

```
if (Platform.isWindows()) {
                in = Loader.class.getResourceAsStream(
                        "/natives/i386/ftd2xx.dll");
            }
```

I have checked, and Platform.isWindows() does return true. I have also checked to see if the file exists in the folder (I copied and pasted the folder into my project) and it does see the file. However, the Loader.class.getResourseAsStream sets in as null. Can someone please either help me get this working or provide some other solution in some other language. I don't mind doing this in another language, but preferably java.

Thanks!

Comment: You downloaded the 64bit version, but you are working with the 32bit ftd2xx.dll (i386 in the path), I will start to investigate from that.